# How to check where there is a special function under a directory

Tags: centos, text

in the directory `/data/repo/`, there are many `.php` files.

I want to know whether in the files there is `eval()` function.

how can I check ?

because I want to check whether there is `One word Trojan` under a directory.

My OS is CentOS 7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the folder run
`grep -lr --include=*.php "eval" .`